# Unable to remove 'Today' link from Kendo datepicker angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to remove 'Today' link from top of the kendo date picker. It should restrict the user to select only Year and not to select Today's date.

`<kendo-datepicker formControlName="bg" [bottomView]="'decade'" [topView]="'decade'" [format]="'dd MMM yyyy'">`

[image: Kendo datepicker]

Comment: What version of Kendo are you using?

Comment: Version is 8.0.0

Comment: Can't you hide it using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no dedicated built-in option to set the visibility of the "Today" UI, so hiding it through CSS is the most straight-forward option, e.g.:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zujtgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Actually when I add this CSS Fix, the other / above div alignment is disturb. Can you please revise the code and provide the css fix for only that part so that other div remain unaffected.

Comment: I am not sure what is meant by "the other/above div alignment is disturb". Both calendars seem to look as expected in all active views (month, year, decade...). Can you share a similar example in which it is clear how hiding the "Today" section in the Calendar affects something else? You could also try hiding the same section with "visibility: hidden" instead of "display: none"